# Custome keyboard disappeared upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard-layout, 20.04, input-method

I had a **custom keyboard layout** (having an Italian keyboard but typing often in Polish I needed a keyboard with Polish letters but with Italian configuration of punctuation).

I just **upgraded from Ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04** and **my custom keyboard disappeared** from the available options. If I go checking in Settings it's still there, but I can't use it (nor changing the input source from the top bar nor from the shortcut). If I add a new language to the list it works properly. **Why is not my custom keyboard working?**
Note that in Ubuntu 19.10 it was working perfectly.

Here is a screenshot as reference: as you can see in the list of Input Sources I have both **rp** (my custom keyboard), Italian, Polish and Russian. But in the drop down menu in the top bar there's no "rp".

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Does `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources show-all-sources true` from a terminal show your keyboard configuration again?

Comment: @starkus thanks for your comment! I tried running your command but I get no answer from the terminal. Was it supposed to be run all in one line?

Comment: Yes, it was. `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources show-all-sources` should show the entry set to true. If you can't see any changes I would try to reboot the system.

Comment: @starkus yes, it displays `true`

Comment: And did your keyboard configuration appear in the drop-down menu?

Comment: I just rebooted and it still doesn't display "rp" among the options :(

Comment: Hm, sad to read. I'm sorry I couldn't help you...

Comment: What does `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources` tell you?

Comment: @starkus `[('xkb', 'rp'), ('xkb', 'it'), ('xkb', 'pl'), ('xkb', 'ru')]`

Comment: Strange. Than `rp` should be shown in the drop-down list... And what happens when you hit the `Super key` + `Space bar`?

Comment: I get displayed again only Italian, Polish and Russian. There must be some configuration file somewhere that was reset during the upgrade...

Comment: I added `pl` to `/etc/default/keyboard` on my system and rebooted, in the login screen I was able to choose Polish but using gnome-shell after logging in, Polish was not shown... Again, sorry that I couldn't help you.

Comment: Maybe, before recreating your custom layout you could try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xkb-data`. From here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions --> Also some links on that outdated page can maybe help you if your settings are not completely overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that your customization included an entry in the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml`. The upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 included an upgrade of the `xkb-data` package, and with that your edited `evdev.xml` file was overwritten.

So you need to redo that part.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Probably this is the problem. I checked the file and there's no entry for my `rp` custom layout. I am trying to find out how I have to edit it, as I actually did this long ago and I totally forgot how to implement that

Comment: Yes, I confirm it! That was the problem :) thanks again! (I then followed this guide to update the `evdev.xml` file: http://people.uleth.ca/~daniel.odonnell/Blog/custom-keyboard-in-linuxx11#c )

Comment: @Robb1: Good to hear. Then you also learned that it's good to save a copy when editing a file which belongs to a package. :)